# How to test Vue Single File Components with Cypress End To End snapshot testing

Tags: vue.js, e2e-testing, cypress

I have a Vue Single File Component that I'm trying to snapshot test with Cypress end-to-end testing and @cypress/snapshot.

An issue could arise if a component's html gets dynamically generated data or attributes. For example, a single file component with scoped CSS styles adds 'data-v-[some hash]' attribute to elements, and if the hash changes the test would fail too.

```
<label class="label" data-v-0ee42ab8="">
```

After rebuild

```
<label class="label" data-v-ca809ab3="">
```

Is there any option to safely ignore parts of snapshot comparison, such as "data-v-*", so tests would still pass? Is snapshot testing not the way to go here, and/or are there better options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it is early days for this plugin, `"version": "0.0.0-development"`.

There does not seems to be an option for customising the compare function, looking at the [source](https://github.com/cypress-io/snapshot/blob/master/src/index.js) it is currently limited to [snap-shot-compare](https://github.com/bahmutov/snap-shot-compare)

**cypress-io / snapshot / src / index.js**

```js
'use strict'

/* global cy, Cypress */
...
const compare = require('snap-shot-compare')
...
function compareValues ({ expected, value }) {
  const noColor = true
  const json = true
  return compare({ expected, value, noColor, json })
}
```

But it is possible to add a wrapper around the compare function.

You will need to make a local copy of the plugin and modify it to reference a custom `compare` function.

***This means you will not be able to directly upgrade to the next official version of the plugin, but need to repeat these steps for each release***

In my React app, I wanted to remove css module hashes from the snapshot before comparing.
The steps I took are as follows:

- npm install --save-dev @cypress/snapshot
- copy the installed folder `node_modules\@cypress\snapshot` to `cypress\support\snapshot`
- changed the `compare` import in `cypress\support\snapshot\src\index.js` to point to a custom comparer, as follows:

  ```js
  // const compare = require('snap-shot-compare')
  const compare = require('./my-compare')
  ```
- added `my-compare.js` to the folder `cypress\support\snapshot\src\` with the following code:

  ```js
  const snapshotCompare = require('snap-shot-compare')

  function compare(data) {

    const filterRegex = /__[^"]+/gm;

    filtered = {
      ...data,
      expected: data.expected.replace(filterRegex, ''),
      value: data.value.replace(filterRegex, '')
    }

    return snapshotCompare(filtered)
  }

  module.exports = compare
  ```

The trickiest bit is getting the regex right. You can probably use the following, check it on [regex101](http://regex101.com).

```js
  const filterRegex = /data-v-[^=]+=""/gm;
```

You can test is crudely by editing the first saved `snapshot.js` before running the second time - e.g change `data-v-` to `datav-`, and watch the test fail since the regex doesn't pick up the mod.

Note that `snapshot.js` has the full text not the filtered text, the regex is only applied for comparison purposes.